# Creating a unique user session ID in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms, session-cookies

I'm not very experienced when it comes to development and I'm trying to secure an application so please bear with me. At the moment, the user is being authenticated and a new session is created using the following code:

```
public static void NewSession(Account account)
        {
            var redirectUrl = "Login.aspx";
            if (account == null)
            {
                var sessionCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["test-app-session"];
                if (sessionCookie != null)
                    ExpireCookie(sessionCookie);
            }
            else
            {
                var sessionCookie = new HttpCookie("test-app-session");
                sessionCookie.Values["account-id"] = account.Id.ToString();
                sessionCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(sessionCookie);

                var redirectCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["test-app-redirect"];
                if (redirectCookie != null)
                {
                    redirectUrl = redirectCookie.Values["url"];
                    ExpireCookie(redirectCookie);
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(redirectUrl))
                    redirectUrl = "Default.aspx";
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }
```

When the App validates the session, it then uses the below code:

```
public static Account FromSession()
        {
            var sessionCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["test-app-session"];
            if (sessionCookie != null && long.TryParse(sessionCookie.Values["account-id"], out long accountId))
            {
                using (var db = Database.Connect())
                {
                    using (var cmd = db.Command("SELECT * FROM Account WHERE id=@id").Parameter("@id", accountId, DbType.Int64))
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        if (reader.Read())
                            return new Account(reader);
                }
            }
            if (!Path.GetFileName(HttpContext.Current.Request.Path).Equals("Login.aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var redirectCookie = new HttpCookie("test-app-redirect");
                redirectCookie.Values["url"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
                redirectCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(redirectCookie);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            }
            return null;
        }
```

The problem is that the account-id value can be easily guessed, so I want to use a unique value for this. I don't really know how I'd implement this, as I'm not sure how the value would then be tied to the users session if there isn't an identifier I can check against. Obviously I'm missing something fundamental in how session management is supposed to work, but I can't figure out what it is. If I create a GUID to store in the cookie, the browser saves it and knows what it is, but how does the server know what this ID is and link it to the user?

Comment: what about adding a UUID column in your table?

Comment: Better yet, why try to roll your own, when you can choose a number of pre-built authentication provides. From the older FBA, or owin, it not clear why you trying to write this kind of code? Those providers shove into viewstate an encrypted "id" (or token) of some sort, and thus it would seem better to use one of those authentication providers that does all this dirty work for you. Furthermore, since those provides work with and play nice with IIS security settings, then you can with great ease say secure some pages for a given role, and do so without having to write one line of code.